# jQuery-ui.min.js conflicts with jquery.easyui.min.js

Tags: javascript

i want to use this two files in my work jquery.easyui.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js. But when i include jquery.easyui.min.js , my site changes. it seems jquery.easyui.min.js  tries to conflict with jquery-ui.min.js. is there a way to fix it so they all work independently

Comment: Have you try https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: You can try to load 2 versions of jQuery one with `noConflict()` one version will hold jQuery UI and the other Easy UI.

Comment: when i use noConflict() it still destroy my look and feel of jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

Most easyui plugins are in conflict with jQueryui, as far as I have done some research. The best thing to do is to use either jquery-ui or jquery-easyui.

Answer (score 0):

If two different frameworks are using the same shortcut, one of them might stop working.
 To avoid conflict between them you can use $.noConflict() function.
for more details check the link 
[jQuery noConflict](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)